# WordPress - wp_editor is not saving what I am typing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a front end post submission form in WordPress. 
Here is my simple code.

```
        $editorSettings = array('quicktags'=>false,'textarea_name'=>'campaign_description');
        wp_editor('Write your content here', '_campaign_description',$editorSettings);
```

Now this weird thing is happening. The content always being submitted in the post is **"Write your content here"**. Its being sent to the post that means the submission is good. The actual problem is whatever I type in the description box, I always get "Write your content here" as the content of the post. On the other hand, if I just use a simple textarea element, I get whatever I type. It seems wp_editor is not getting what I am typing.

I have tried disabling the plugins and switching to default theme but its not working.
Can anyone help me tracking down the issue? What could be the possibilities?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I have also noticed that if the visual tab is not working. I mean if I select "text" tab from wp_editor and the content I type in gets submitted. But this does not happen for visual tab.

Answer (score 0):

'Write your content here' needs to be the saved value - else you will always output that string, eg:

```
// Get your saved value    
$_campaign_description = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_campaign_description', true );
$editorSettings = array('quicktags'=>false,'textarea_name'=>'campaign_description');
// Use your saved value when calling the editor
wp_editor($_campaign_description, '_campaign_description',$editorSettings);
```

Make sure $post->ID is your post ID however you reference it

Comment: Thank you for taking interest. Have you checked the updated part? "I have also noticed that if the visual tab is not working. I mean if I select "text" tab from wp_editor and the content I type in gets submitted. But this does not happen for visual tab."

Comment: Maybe you could add in your full code and show us how you save the data as well. The main issue will have been the 'Write your content here' issue. Happy to look more into it if you can provide more code :)